# The type parameter FooEntity is hiding the type FooEntity

Tags: java, generics

```
public interface IFoo<TKey, FooEntity<TValue>> {
  // stuff
}
```

I get this error:
**The type parameter FooEntity is hiding the type FooEntity**

```
public class FooEntity<T> {

    private T foo;


}
```

how can i fix this?

I want to be able to implement IFoo Interface somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this:

```
public interface IFoo<TKey, FooEntity<TValue>> {
  // stuff
}
```

You are defining an interface named IFoo. When defining a type, the things between `<` and `>` are *type parameters*. The actual types should be supplied when using this IFoo interface, not when you define IFoo.

Do you really mean this:

```
public interface IFoo<TKey, TValue> {
    void doSomething(TKey key, FooEntity<TValue> value);
}
```

And

```
public class MyFoo implements IFoo<String, Integer> {
    @Override
    public void doSomething(String key, FooEntity<Integer> value) {
        // TODO: ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try...

```
class FooEntity<K> {  } 

interface IFoo<K,V> {  } 

class IFooImplElseWere<K,V> implements IFoo<K,V> {  }

IFoo<String, FooEntity<String>> ifi = new IFooImplElseWere<String,FooEntity<String>>();
```